# Combining 2 rows into 1 row with condition

Tags: mysql

I have tables like this in mySQL

Table 1

```
| ID   | Name        | Time                  | Status    |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 1    | John        | 2018-12-17 08:14:17   | In        |
| 1    | John        | 2018-12-17 17:14:18   | Out       |
| 1    | John        | 2018-12-19 08:14:19   | In        |
| 1    | John        | 2018-12-19 17:14:39   | Out       |
| 2    | Sarah       | 2018-12-17 08:03:29   | In        |
| 2    | Sarah       | 2018-12-17 17:24:15   | Out       |
| 2    | Sarah       | 2018-12-18 08:04:11   | In        |
| 2    | Sarah       | 2018-12-18 17:05:49   | Out       |
```

Table 2

```
| ID   | Name        | 
----------------------
| 1    | John        |
| 2    | Sarah       |
```

I would like to get this result

```
| ID   | Name        | In                    | Out                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1    | John        | 2018-12-17 08:14:17   | 2018-12-17 17:14:18   |
| 1    | John        | 2018-12-19 08:14:19   | 2018-12-19 17:14:39   |
| 2    | Sarah       | 2018-12-17 08:03:29   | 2018-12-17 17:24:15   |
| 2    | Sarah       | 2018-12-18 08:04:11   | 2018-12-18 17:05:49   |
```

I've tried using this code

```
SELECT 
t2.`ID`,
t2.`Name`,
MAX(CASE WHEN t1.`Status` = 'In' THEN t1.`Time` END) In,
MAX(CASE WHEN t1.`Status` = 'Out' THEN t1.`Time` END) Out
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
ON t1.`ID` = t2.`ID`
GROUP BY t2.`Name`
```

How could I achieve that?

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: What do you expect to see if a check in (or out) is missing?  Eg, Sarah forgot to check in on the 18th, so she has in, out, out?  What if somebody has checked in on the 18th, but checked out on the 19th, is that valid?

Comment: You'll also need to check what happens if someone checks in and out twice on the same day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your current query. Firstly, you are using reserved words as column aliases without escaping them in backticks. Secondly, you need to also group by `t2.ID` to avoid full_group_by issues. Finally you need to group by `DATE(t1.time)` to get In/Out times on a daily basis. Try this:

```
SELECT 
t2.`ID`,
t2.`Name`,
MAX(CASE WHEN t1.`Status` = 'In' THEN t1.`Time` END) AS `In`,
MAX(CASE WHEN t1.`Status` = 'Out' THEN t1.`Time` END) AS `Out`
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
ON t1.`ID` = t2.`ID`
GROUP BY t2.ID, t2.`Name`,DATE(t1.time)
```

Output:

```
ID  Name    In                  Out
1   John    2018-12-17 08:14:17 2018-12-17 17:14:18
1   John    2018-12-19 08:14:19 2018-12-19 17:14:39
2   Sarah   2018-12-17 08:03:29 2018-12-17 17:24:15
2   Sarah   2018-12-18 08:04:11 2018-12-18 17:05:49
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hiJGYtNhJAp72qH9RXVJc7/10)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using adding `date(Time) in group by clause`

```
SELECT 
t2.`ID`,
t2.`Name`,
MAX(CASE WHEN t1.`Status` = 'In' THEN t1.`Time` END) In,
MAX(CASE WHEN t1.`Status` = 'Out' THEN t1.`Time` END) Out
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
ON t1.`ID` = t2.`ID`
GROUP BY t2.`Name`,date(Time)
```